# data encoding for columns with repeating values

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to create a NN on Pytorch using python.
My input values are:

['month', 'day', 'week_day', 'classname_ml', 'departure_country', 'departure_city',
'departure', 'arrival', 'arrival_city', 'arrival_country']

output - ideally a coefficient (they range from 0.05 to 0.55)
But for now - encoding.
I have left month, day and weekday as they are (int values)
I have assigned each city with a number (both in departure_city and arrival_city) and same for countries and airports.
Was it a good solution? (according to [data encoding](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-categorical-input-handling-for-neural-networks-c172ba552dee) it wasn't)
Also do I have to make the values between 0 and 1 or can I keep them as ints?

Thank you if you read this far.
Would appriciate all the help I can get.